# How to design the following in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, calendar

I just need a dialog/fragment to show the year with left,right arrows and the months of the year in gridview below it.

The current month enabled and rest all disabled.

This is what i need:

[image]

Comment: Can you post what have you tried and where you are stuck

Comment: @NayanSrivastava I tried some custom calendars, but they didnt work the way i want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `spinner` with custom adapter and layout to achieve this. Using `DialogFragment` or `AlertDialog` will not give you exact look how ever that also can be used.

Trying with dialogFragment you can render one `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`.